# Angular2: Interface dependency injection with provide()

Tags: angular, ionic2

Is there an example how/where to define dependency injection using provide() function?

I want to map class and value to an interface:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/provide-function.html

Tryed to do it like this in app.js:

```
import {provide, Injector} from 'angular2/angular2';

export interface EnvSettings {
    apiUrl: string;
}
var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
  provide(EnvSettings, {useValue: {apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/'}}),
  //provide(Engine, {useClass: Engine}),
]);
```

Getting an error:

```
Uncaught Token must be defined!
```

Answer (score 2):

Your token cannot be an interface (which disappear with transpilation).
You can however create a specific Token for that purpose, like so:

```
export let EnvSettingsToken = new OpaqueToken('env.settings');
```

Comment: OK, but how do I cast it to a required type?

Is it better to define a base class instead of interface?